# Magento CE 2.2 Huge Catalog Indexing Issue

Tags: mysql, indexing, magento2

Updated to  Latest Magento 2.2.5

Index : **catalogsearch_fulltext** never completes.

Catalog Size:-

```
Store View: 10
Category: 33K 
Products: 300K
```

Following index take huge time (2+hr) to complete :

```
catalog_product_category
catalog_product_attribute
```

and following index never completes

```
catalogsearch_fulltext
```

Using Elastic Search from Mirasvit as well.

Totak Mysql Database Size = ~30+GB

still no results with index

Comment: Let's see the SQL commands.

Answer (score 2):

`This is happening because of multiple store view, is actually easy to manage; in Magento 2.2.5, indexers are scoped and multi-threaded to support reindexing in parallel mode. This feature reduces processing time. It parallelizes by the indexer’s dimension and executes across multiple threads. This means that you can catalogsearch_fulltext can be run in parallel mode:`
`the` `following command runs the Catalog Search Fulltext indexer across three threads:`

`MAGE_INDEXER_THREADS_COUNT=3 php -f bin/magento indexer:reindex catalogsearch_fulltext`

learn more https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-index.html#view-indexer-status